# Python pyinstaller running exe on 32-bit computer

Tags: python, 32-bit, pyinstaller

I wrote a Python script (includes Tkinter) using Python 2.7.9 in Spyder (from Anaconda 2.2.0) and my computer is a 64-bit operating system. I made an executable file from the Python script using pyinstaller and I tried running the exe on a different computer. The computer I need to run it on is a 32-bit operating system and it gave me an error saying my exe file needed to be compatible with the 32-bit system. I tried dowloading the Python 32-bit version and creating the exe file from that Python version. Unfortunately, that did not work. Is there a way I can make this exe file work on the 32-bit computer?

Edit: I installed pyinstall(32-bit version) and pywin32(32-bit version) and made the executable file with python 32-bit version and it made the exe file fine. However, nothing happens when I try to run the exe file. I also noticed the exe file I made with the 32-bit version was only 6,400KB while the 64-bit version of the same file was 124,000KB. I don't know if it matters but I'm using --onefile and --windowed when making the exe file. Any help is appreciated!